# Does a weight attached to a string over a spinning pulley count as a transfer of kinetic to rotational energy?

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics

More specifically, if I had a weight hanging on one end of a pulley at some height h (the other end of the string continues onto another pulley) and I let it go, would the kinetic energy gained from the weight falling be transferred as rotational kinetic energy to the pulley?  Or would the kinetic energy of the falling weight and the spinning pulley be considered the "same" energy? In even simpler terms, are plain kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy the same thing?
[image: Picture of System Described]

Comment: So, $I\omega^2/2$ is also kinetic energy, and if you break a system into it's particles you can write $\sum m_i v_i^2/2 = (Mv^2 + I \omega^2)/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is not a transfer of kinetic energy from the weight to the pulley. Rather, the pulley accelerates slower and then reach a lower speed because part of the work done by gravity is directly transformed into rotational energy of the pulleys. Yes, both translational and rotational motion energy are forms of kinetic energy.